# MS Access query trouble

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to count how many products are associated with each of our female customers so I can use it in a later calculation.

```
SELECT [Customers].Customer_ID
FROM [Customers]
WHERE ((([Customers].Gender)='Female'))
GROUP BY [Customers].Customer_ID;
```

The above SQL gives me a list of ID's for our female customers. Now, I guess in a separate query, I need to count the number of Product ID's for each of the ID's in the above list, but I don't know where to go from here. I don't know if I can combine this step into the above query, or if I need to do something else.

I am thinking I need something like this:

```
DCount("Order_ID", "Orders", "Customer_ID = [**how do I make it to where 
this equals the resulting Customer_ID's from the above query**]" )
```

Can someone please help? Am I on the right track?

If you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: Which table has the products? table `Orders` ?

Comment: `GROUP BY [Customers].Customer_ID` suggests that `Customer_ID` is not unique in the `Customers` table. Is that really true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT [Customers].Customer_ID
     , COUNT(*) AS NumOrders
FROM [Customers]
  INNER JOIN [Orders]
    ON [Orders].Customer_ID = [Customers].Customer_ID
WHERE ([Customers].Gender = 'Female')
GROUP BY [Customers].Customer_ID;
```

---

The `INNER JOIN` should be changed into `LEFT JOIN` **to include Customers without any Orders** (and `COUNT(*)` should be changed to `COUNT(Orders.Customer_ID)` as @onedaywhen spotted):

```
SELECT [Customers].Customer_ID
     , COUNT(Orders.Customer_ID) AS NumOrders
FROM [Customers]
  LEFT JOIN [Orders]
    ON [Orders].Customer_ID = [Customers].Customer_ID
WHERE ([Customers].Gender = 'Female')
GROUP BY [Customers].Customer_ID;
```

**Note**, that the above queries will give you **number of Orders** and not number of **Products** as you describe. You'll have to provide the structure of the tables (probably `Orders`, or `OrderDetails` if you have such a table) so we know where the information about products (and their orders) is stored.

---

---

Sidenote: as (again, deserving more than half of these points :) @onedaywhen spotted, the `Customer_ID` is supposed to be the `PRIMARY KEY` of table `[Customers]`. If that's the case (or if it is `UNIQUE`), your original query could be simplified:

```
SELECT [Customers].Customer_ID
FROM [Customers]
WHERE [Customers].Gender = 'Female' ;
```

Comment: For your outer join suggestion presumably `COUNT(*)` should be changed to `COUNT(Orders.Customer_ID)`, otherwise a customer with zero orders would have the same count as a customer with one order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Haven't tested it since I don't got MS Access on this PC.
Similar stuff work in MySQL and MS SQL so it might work :)

```
SELECT SUM(O.Order_ID), C.Customer_ID
FROM [Orders] AS O, [Customers] AS C
WHERE C.Customer_ID IN (
SELECT [Customers].Customer_ID
FROM [Customers]
WHERE ((([Customers].Gender)='Female'))
GROUP BY [Customers].Customer_ID);
```